# problemas con las fecha en json (php)

Tags: php, json

esperando que todos se encuentren muy bien de salud, les comento que estoy realizando un llamado de datos y que se cargue a través de un spinner, a través de mysql, el código en php me arroja problemas con el json con las fechas en particular, como se ve a continuación:

```
{"prueba":[{"id":"1","Denuncia":"01\/09\/2022","Siniestro":"30\/08\/2022","Numero":"398123456"}]}
```

por otro lado, cuando hago las pruebas a través de postmann me muestra bien los datos sin error alguno en la fechas, por eso les presento el código que se realizó, para tal operación, soy nuevo en estas lides de android ya que estoy aprendiendo, ya he aprendido varias cosas, pero en esta no he podido solucionar el problema:

```
<?php
include_once './conexion2.php';
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$respuesta = array();
$respuesta ["prueba"] = array();
$con = mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect server ");
mysqli_select_db($con,"$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql="SELECT ID,Fecha_Denuncia,Fecha_Siniestro,N_Siniestro FROM casos";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$tmp = array();
$tmp ["id"] = $row["ID"];
$tmp ["Denuncia"] = $row["Fecha_Denuncia"];
$tmp ["Siniestro"] = $row["Fecha_Siniestro"];
$tmp ["Numero"] = $row["N_Siniestro"];
array_push($respuesta ["prueba"], $tmp);
}
echo json_encode($respuesta);
?>
```

mi consulta como se puede arreglar tal situación, los campos de las fechas las tengo declaradas como varchar, para que me arroje el resultado mencionado con anterioridad, desde ya muchas gracias.

Amigos raelice todas las pruebas visual studio code a travé de php-json y no hay problema, ahora lo lleve a través de android studio y me sigue dando este error:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value {"prueba":[{"id":"1","Denuncia":"01\/09\/2022","Siniestro":"30\/08\/2022","Numero":"398123456"}]} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

ya no se a que se deba, favor de ayudarme, lo otro si necesitan el código de android me informan y desde ya muchas gracias y disculpen las molestias

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema, los caracteres de escapa? Si no los quieres, usa `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES`, algo así: `echo json_encode($respuesta, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);`, pero **ten cuidado**, si no hilas fino con la codificación, podrías tener problemas, por ejemplo, si hubiera datos acentuados. Realmente, tus fechas como se presentan ahora no son erróneas.

Comment: @A.Cedano muchas gracias por tu ayuda, con  la que me presentaste del json encode me funciona bien, te pasaste en serio.

Comment: @A.Cedano realice unas pruebas con un nuevo campo Des":"Da\u00f1os materiales por colisi\u00f3n" y me arrojo este resultado y debe decir "Daños materiales por colisión", es bien complicado json como me lo mencionaste con anterioridad el tema de los acentos

Comment: @A.Cedano muchas gracias por tu ayuda, el problema ya supe de donde era el error, en el php-json cambie todo el código de una manera más sencilla y me arroja lo que quería que me mostrara el campo clave, ahora a seguir aprendiendo y como hago que al momento de escoger una dato del spinner me muestre los datos en las cajas de texto, y nuevamente mil gracias, ya que estuve cono una semana tratando de aprender y solucionarlo

Comment: Me alegro de que te haya servido. Como te dije, el que el JSON venga de ese modo no es ningún problema, cuando sea leído convertirá esos carácteres en un formato entendible, claro está, si usas correctamente el parseo. De todos modos, conviene siempre configurar `utf8` a nivel global en los siguientes entornos: HTML, PHP, conexión a la base de datos, definición de tablas y columnas en la base de datos. Para más detalle sobre esto puedes consultar [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/59489/29967).

Answer (score 0):

Tal como te señaló @A.Cedano ese JSON es válido, en postman te lo muestra correctamente porque lo parsea.

Si yo hago lo mismo veras que los backslash desaparecen

```js
let json=`{"prueba":[{"id":"1","Denuncia":"01\/09\/2022","Siniestro":"30\/08\/2022","Numero":"398123456"}]}`;

console.log( JSON.parse( json ) );
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda y comentario, si te puedo realizar una consulta, la linea de la console donde la coloco en el php o en el android studio, desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: @Hector Creo que no me entendiste, trataré de explicar nuevamente: El json es un texto plano. Luego uno no trabaja sobre ese texto plano, lo que se hace es transfórmalo a un objeto. Cuando ese texto es transformado, esos backslash desaparecen. El ejemplo que yo puse te demuestra eso, este ejemplo está en javascript. Por último, aclaro, que puede haber una posibilidad de que al transformar el texto plano, caracteres "raros" no desaparezcan, esto se debe a que la codificación no es la misma que se usó para serializarlo, en este caso hay que indicar esa codificación

Comment: muchas gracias por tu comentario y ayuda, el problema ya supe de donde era el error, en el php-json cambie todo el código de una manera más sencilla y me arroja lo que quería que me mostrar el campo clave, ahora a seguir aprendiendo y como hago que al momento de escoger una dato del spinner me muestre los datos en las cajas de texto, y neuvamente il gracias, ya que estuve cono una semana tratando de aprender y solucionarlo